# iOS Table View Finding A Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cells. Cells have an image view, a label and a progress view. What I want to achieve is to update progress view in a specific cell according to the event that fires. My idea is to find the cell by name label that is in the event and then update progress view. This may not be an efficient way but I couldn't think of some other way. Other ideas are also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a NSDictionary with the name as the key and the NSIndexPath as the object. Then to can look up the index path for a given cell using the name in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` has a 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method that should give you the cell for a specific row.

i.e. something like

```
// Get visible cell for data item
NSInteger row = [myArrayOfThings indexOfObject:thing];
NSIndexPath *inedexPath = [NSIndexPath alloc] initWithRow:row section:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indeexPath];

// Update cell here ...
...
```

Disclaimer : Code typed from memory - you may have to look at the documentation for some of the method names :)

Answer (score 0):

the more better way is with tag,

you can give each cell a unique tag and access that cell by this method

```
//method of UIView(UIViewHierarchy)
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag;
// can be used like this
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView viewwithtag:tag];
```

Comment: Won't that only work if the table view doesn't recycle the cells?

Comment: If you have 100 rows but only display 7 recycled cells how can there be 100 unique identifiers - the cells will recycled! Are you planning to retag the cell every time it is displayed?